# Thyristor in a choppercircuit

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, energy, duty-cycle, thyristor

I've the following kown values:

1. Switching on loss is \$\text{E}_\text{on}\space\text{J}\$ in \$t_\text{on}=\tau_\text{on}\space\text{s}\$
2. Switching off loss is \$\text{E}_\text{off}\space\text{J}\$ in \$t_\text{off}=\tau_\text{off}\space\text{s}\$
3. In the pass state we have \$\text{P}_\text{pass}\space\text{W}\$
4. In the blocking state we have \$\text{P}_\text{block}\space\text{W}\$
5. The chopperfrequency is equal to \$\text{f}_\text{c}\$ hertz

> Question: Find the maximum duty cyle, when the heat sink on the thyristor can handle \$\text{P}_\text{hs}\$ watts of power?

---

My work (I use total energy per period):

$$\text{E}_\text{on}+\text{P}_\text{pass}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{f}_\text{c}}-\tau_\text{on}\right\}+\text{E}_\text{off}+\text{P}_\text{block}\cdot\left\{\frac{1-\text{d}}{\text{f}_\text{c}}-\tau_\text{off}\right\}\le\frac{\text{P}_\text{hs}}{\text{f}_\text{c}}$$

Now, solving \$\text{d}\$ will give me the answer.

> Question: Can I do this also using power instead of energy?

$$\color{red}{\text{d}\cdot\left(\text{P}_\text{pass}-\frac{\text{E}_\text{on}}{\tau_\text{on}}\right)+\left(1-\text{d}\right)\cdot\left(\text{P}_\text{block}-\frac{\text{E}_\text{off}}{\tau_\text{off}}\right)=\text{P}_\text{hs}-\text{f}_\text{c}\cdot\left(\text{E}_\text{on}+\text{E}_\text{off}\right)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Can I do this also using power instead of energy?

Yes, you can convert switching energy losses to power losses by multiplying the energy loss (per cycle) by operating frequency fc. This produces watts numerically and is independent of duty cycle.

So, those fixed switching losses are ever present and can be subtracted from the target power loss (P\$_{hs}\$) leaving just the power value that is based only on duty cycle.

Given that you have numbers for on_power loss and off_power loss this would appear to be the easier route to take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do that how can I find the maximum duty cyle?

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer making it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: I dont get what you say. Can you set it in a equation?

Comment: You start with Phs and subtract the power losses due to switching ((Eon+Eoff) x fc). Are you OK so far?

Comment: Yes I do, that's clear, we have: $$\text{P}_{\text{hs}}-\text{f}_{\text{c}}\cdot\left(\text{E}_\text{on}+\text{E}_\text{off}\right)$$. Now how to continue?

Comment: Then you have (d).Ppass and (1-d).Pblock BUT you have to individually reduce those powers to account for the small section of duty cycle stolen by Ton and Toff.

Comment: can you see my edit in my question, the red part is that what I've to calculate?

Comment: I think that it is not right.....!

Comment: I think it would be [(d).Ppass] - Eon/Ton and similarly for Pblock. Are we in danger of turning what is a question and answer site into a forum? It is frowned upon.

Comment: That is not true, because when I use values for all the variables it gave me another answer for the duty cycle then when I use the energy way

Comment: It all depends how you look at d. Anyway, wasn't this question about how to convert energies to powers and solve? My answer modifies d to account for the Ton time. I guess there are several ways of doing it and I don't want to get into a long winded discussion on this way or that way. It's been a long day!